# Android - position layout at bottom of screen always in the foreground

Tags: android, android-layout

My xml file is like following:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
       <LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

First LinearLayout has `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, all others `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. How to create a layout at bottom of screen always in the foreground with an imageview?

Comment: I didn't understand yor question but this may work for you ? : `<ImageView .. android:layout_alignParentBottom="" />`

Comment: I need a layout, relative or linear, because I don't need only a simple ImageView... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done with a relative layout. Relative layout elements stack on top of each other unless you position them relative to each other. For instance, if you had two image views and did position them, the second image view would be placed on top of the first one.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
     </ScrollView>
     <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:contentDescription="@string/YOUR_CONTENT_DESC"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I already tried to change the first LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout, and I had put a linearlayout at the bottom of the screen, and the scrollview not longer worked.

Comment: I've done this in numerous applications that have a buttons at the bottom of the screen. The linear layout inside the scroll view is where you put your content that you want to scroll.

Comment: It's true, the LinearLayout after the ScrollView with the RelativeLayout works correctly. Thank you a lot, can you edit your answer putting the ImageView in a LinearLayout for the future people interested in this question?

Answer (score 0):

you could set the gravity of the linear layout to bottom.

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

When your creating your XML document order does matter. So for example:

```
<ImageView/>
<LinearLayout/>
```

The LinearLayout will be placed in front of the ImageView.

Comment: It doesn't work. I added the linearlayout with android:layout_gravity="bottom" below the </ScrollView> and the linearlayout appears below the scrollview, not at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: have you tried putting the linearlayout inside of the scroll view?

Comment: The linearlayout must be always in the foreground.

Comment: it should still be in the foreground... being inside of the scrollview shouldnt affect that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem with another one alternative.**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>
</FrameLayout>
```